# Open more then one instance of tor proggremly

Tags: configuration, firefox

I am trying to open more then one instance of tor browser with different identities with c#.

One of the brwoswers opens fine:

[image]

But when the code opens the second I get empty browser:

[image]

Here is my c# code:

```
 IWebDriver browser;

            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
            profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
            profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150);
            browser =  new FirefoxDriver(profile);
            //    browser.Quit();

            //Firefox's proxy driver executable is in a folder already
            //  on the host system's PATH environment variable.
            browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://dnsleaktest.com");
            //IWebElement header = browser.FindElement(By.Id(“site - header"));

            //Assert.True(header.Displayed);
            // browser.Close();

            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            IWebDriver browser2;

            FirefoxProfile profile2 = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile2.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
            profile2.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1");
            profile2.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9152);
            browser2 = new FirefoxDriver(profile2);
            //    browser.Quit();

            //Firefox's proxy driver executable is in a folder already
            //  on the host system's PATH environment variable.
            browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://dnsleaktest.com");
            //IWebElement header = browser.FindElement(By.Id(“site - header"));

            //Assert.True(header.Displayed);
            // browser.Close();
```

Please correct my English if needed

Comment: That's not Tor Browser. That's Firefox configured to use a socks proxy (that just happens to be a Tor process).

Comment: (This problem may just the result of a really silly coding error by the user, partially due to poor coding style. Note that the second instantiation of the browser is done with `browser.Nagivate()` rather than `browser2.Navigate()`. The code creates two instances of  `FirefoxDriver()` but only ever *uses* one. Also, this question is entirely unrelated to Tor so I'm flagging it to be closed.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about some browser instrumentation library, not Tor.